# Encrypt/Decrypt Small Messages in C on Microcontroller

Tags: c, encryption, embedded, aes, microcontroller

What libraries exist for secure encryption in an embedded context.  Not embedded linux, though.  I'm talking about the simplest option, running on bare-metal with no operating system and no  to get access to a filestream.

Think chips talking to each other on a printed circuit board, periodically sending like 10-byte messages.

rijndael? Is it worth the time to try to port it to something simpler?

Comment: tea, xtea?  Comments must be at least 15 characters in length...

Comment: "is it worth the time" - the answer alwas comes down to "what does it cost" vs "what does it buy me". Only you can answer that for your situation.

Comment: Rijndael is AES.  Just use some AES library.

Comment: the "[encryption tag](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption)" at Electronics Stackexchange has a lot of discussion of encryption on small microcontrollers.

Answer (score 1):

A number of manufacturers provide examples of encryption algorithms for their processors.  Here is one for the [TI MSP430 processor family](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa547/slaa547.pdf).  I would recommend using with caution and a full investigation of the security impacts of your own implementation.  Key management as always is a major problem, particularly how you keep this secure if the device is accessible by an attacker.

Other algorithms that are readily available are [Twofish](https://www.schneier.com/twofish.html) and [Blowfish](https://www.schneier.com/blowfish.html) by Bruce Schneier.

You can also use a standard hash on a shared key plus some message varying data known to both ends (time or message count spring to mind) to produce a "random" array of bytes that can be XORed over the message data.